# DD-WRT Acces Point as a Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

Following suggestion to this question asked on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/wireless-routers-bridge-themselves-automatically), I am asking the question here.

> this is an extension to my previous question (I think it was deleted), where I was claiming that DDWRT was disabling it's DHCP server once connected to the network. I was wrong, as it now seems that it is bridging itself with another parallel connected wireless router.
>
> I have two Draytek 2820 and one Netgear WG602v3 with latest DDWRT. Lets call one wired-Draytek and it has wireless disabled. The other one, let's call it wireless-Draytek, is connected to wired-Draytek and has wireless with MAC filtering enabled.
>
> Once I connect Netgear to the wired-Draytek, the client that connects to Netgear, will be assigned with IP address from the wireless-Draytek. If the MAC address is not on the wireles-Draytek, the client is unable to obtain IP address and has no connectivity at all, even with manually assigned static IP configuration.
>
> To illustrate further, this is how network is set up:
>
> ```
> wired-Draytek ---------- wireless-Draytek
>               \_________ Netgear
> ```
>
> What I wish to have, is that Netgear issues IP addresses from it's own IP pool and ignores the MAC filtering rules from wireless-Draytek.
>
> This is kind of puzzling how this they are bridging (if they are) themselves automatically.
>
> Thanks.
>
> **UPDATE:**
>
> It's not a home network. I gave you a bit simplified set-up. If there is a better site on Stack Exchange to ask this, please let me know.
>
> The Drayteks are running stock firmware, it's only Netgear that I've flashed to get more stability. In addition to these routers, I have also three 3COM Baseline switch 2824, and another Draytek router with Prosafe FS752TP PoE switch dedicated for VoIP phones.
>
> Wired-Draytek has IP 10.0.0.1, DHCP disabled as there is AD DC which is issuing IP addresses. Wireless-Draytek has IP 1.1.1.1 and DHCP enabled. Netgear has default - 192.168.1.1.
>
> As per suggestion, the specific question is - how do I isolate these two wireless routers?

Comment: So all the devices are configured to function as a router (not bridge)? To both wireless-Draytek and Netgear clients connect only over WiFi? How is DHCP configured on the Netgear?

Comment: They are connected over Ethernet cable. DHCP is configured as DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Netgear WG602v3 is a wireless access point and does not have the processing power or memory to do any real router duties even if re-purposed with new firmware and configuration. The 2mb of flash and 8mb of ram is very limiting.

In a network (LAN side interconnected with wired or wireless links) DHCP broadcasts will be answered by all DHCP servers on the LAN with the client picking the one that responded first.

If you do want to use it as a router makes sure: `Setup -> Networking: Port Setup: Wan Port Assignment: eth0` also makes sure you use a different SSID than the Draytek so clients don't try to roam between them.